# Showing only the content of a file from a directory(given as parameter ) or his subdirectories which has .txt extension, using grep

Tags: linux, grep

I managed to do this using find:

```
find 'directory' -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

I have no clue how can I do it using grep. Tried to do it thousand times.

Comment: Why do you need a `grep`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you want to do with `grep`.  Do you want to run `grep` for all matching files and finally get the output of `grep`, i.e. replace `cat` with `grep`? Or do you want to use `grep` as an additional criteria to select files that should be sent to stdout with `cat`? Or do you want to filter the file names with `grep` instead of `find`?

Comment: Needed **grep** because I heard that I can do it also with **grep** and it was a challenge for me to do it other way. I don't know where it should have been included, tried it many ways. Found the perfect answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -bR | grep -E '^*.\.txt$' | xargs cat
```

List file recursively using -R and use -b to escape any none printable characters/spaces. Grep the listing for any entries that end with ".txt" and then pipe the result to xargs cat.